# Create dataframe from dictionary where arrays are of unequal length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary - `{'Car': ['a', 'b'], 'Bike': ['q', 'w', 'e']}`

I want to generate a data frame like this -

```
S.no. | vehicle | model
1     | Car     | a
2     | Car     | b
2     | Bike     | q
2     | Bike     | w
2     | Bike     | e
```

I tried `df = pd.DataFrame(vDict)` but I get `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` error. Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
pd.Series(dct, name='model').explode().rename_axis(index='vehicle').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` here, then use `stack` and finally clean up our index and column names:

```
dct = {'Car': ['a', 'b'], 'Bike': ['q', 'w', 'e']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index').stack()
df = df.reset_index(level=0, name='model').rename(columns={'level_0':'vehicle'})
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
  vehicle model
0     Car     a
1     Car     b
2    Bike     q
3    Bike     w
4    Bike     e
```